# How can I get custom CSS to work with LiveAgent?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, css, liveagent

I need to add a custom message to the waiting page for Live Agent.
I've designed a basic VisualForce page to use for testing. 
This page includes custom CSS.

Well, really it's not custom CSS. I found the CSS that Salesforce uses for Live Agent, uploaded it as a Static Resource, and am referencing it in the VisualForce page by adding `<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.EVChatWindow}" />`.

I've set up the Chat Buttons, Deployment, and Site according to the instructions in the Live Agent Developer Guide. I'm able to open the chat window fine, but the styles don't seem to be loading correctly.

(I'm happy to provide more information - just let me know if there's anything else I need to include)